# How i can edit TreeTableView javafx?

Tags: java, treetableview

I have TreeTableView, with 2 columns(column1,column2). In first I have strings(names of properties), in second i have some info, what I want to change. And I can't find answer for my question all day. treeTableView is editable, column2 is editable. But when I click on in cells - nothing happends, i feel realy stupid, couse it must be so easy. Help me please. 
If u can say something about other thing i must do, I'll be thankful; The other thing is hiding and showing treeItem's by checkbox;

```
TreeItem<SomeClass> treeItem;
```

and

```
publick void SomeClass{String someProperty; boolean visible; }
```

and there is getter and setter for "visible"

Comment: Please add more code since we can't help you with only little.
Reduce your code to the bare minimum so that we can understand it easily.

Comment: i solve a prodlem, i find info about TreeView, thanks_)